# AWS API Gateway authorizer google sign in

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, google-signin

I have an API Gateway/lambda REST API that is being accessed from a react web app. I need to add authentication using google as an identity provider. The app should also keep the user signed in.

I understand when the user first grants access to the (react) client app, it should send the ID token to my backend, which should then verify the token.

Since my architecture is serverless, I assume the verifying should be done in the API Gateway authorizer function, which then grants access to the API on successful verification of the token.

My question is, how do I then create a persistent session? Should I be saving anything to my database about the user? Does the token need to be verified on every API call?

Should the authorizer be checking if the user is already registered or if it's a new user?

Comment: Are you using Cognito?

Comment: @AndrewA. Not currently. The only form of persistence i'm using is DynamoDB.

Comment: So you're developing your own authorizer function in Lambda to use Google as an identity provider?

Comment: @AndrewA. Well i've assumed thats what should be done. I really have no idea what I'm doing though. I want to use google as the identity provider for authentication.

Answer (score 8):

It would be easiest to use AWS Cognito for this. Configure a user pool as an authorizer for your API gateway and then configure Google as an identity provider for that user pool. This link might be helpful: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/google.html. Cognito even has a hosted UI if you want to use it for signing users in.

As for your question about persisting user sessions, they usually get persisted in local storage in the browser or in a cookie or some similar mechanism. You can also persist them on the server-side in a database like you were mentioning but that isn't really for authentication purposes.

The user session will contain an access token. The access token is short-lived, meaning you can only use them for an hour usually. After that you have to use a separate refresh token to generate a new access token. And to be extra safe the refresh token itself will expires after a few days (and you have to sign back in).

Comment: That make things much clearer thank you. Would I be able to limit access to only white listed emails using this method? Or does adding that constraint make doing it through a token authorizer more sense? I was thinking checking the user is on the whitelist in the authorizer function would be simple enough.

Comment: In AWS Cognito you can create a pre-signup trigger - which is a lambda function that runs before completing the user sign-up. There is an example on how to restrict email addresses to one domain here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html#aws-lambda-triggers-pre-registration-example